# How to enable checkbox selection on click hold on a row in mui Data grid table

Tags: reactjs, node.js, material-ui, datagrid, material-table

I am in the search of solution that when i hold click on mui data grid table row for some seconds, then checkbox selection enable, and when i just click on row then only that show should select.

```
import React from "react";
import "./datatable.scss";
import { DataGrid } from "@mui/x-data-grid";

const DataTable = ({ columns, rows }) => {

  return (
    <div className="datatable">

      <DataGrid
        className="dataGrid"
        rows={rows}
        columns={columns}
        pageSize={5}
        rowsPerPageOptions={[5]}
        checkboxSelection={false}
        disableRowSelectionOnClick
       
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default DataTable;
```

Comment: Try using `mousedown` event with a timeout to enable check box